# Moving library/module outside of node_modules

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

I am working on angular 7.

I have one node package that i want to customize for my project.

The issue is it's node package so it will be install fresh on npm install on server.

So i want to move this library into local folder.

I am not sure how to do this. Can anyone give me any suggestion?

I want to customize this library [multi select dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown).

Comment: Not a really good practice, but you could add it in your `assets` folder and in the `scripts` of your `angular.json` file.

Comment: How can i do that. This is not just straight js file which i can add in scripts. It's angular2/typescript package.

Comment: Then get the folder and add it in your `src` folder so that it gets compiled

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options on how to do this:

- If the changes you want to make are generic, you could make them and create a pull request for the project on Github.
- You could fork the project and use your own version of the library. Everyone in the team will install this one.
- If there are a few changes only, you could use something like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to make and distribute them.

Comment: I just want to do some changes in some files & want to keep those changes. So want a way to move the folder of that library outside of node_modules.